# What's the best solution for solving this situation with Semaphores?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I want to try out Java Semaphores, so I thought about this problem:

There's a train station and two railways are crossing, one to the east and another one to the south. So of course we should get sensors at the end of the cross for each rail which tell us when a train has crossed and the southern or eastern railway can allow its trains to start.

So far, I think sensors would be `Semaphores`, Trains classes would be `Threads` and I could have any sort of railway classes where I throw the trains to run.

[image: Model for problem]

I'm a newbie with Java Semaphores, any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Then the crossing would be your common (and critical) resource. Did you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "did you have any ideas yourself"?

Comment: Ideas what the code should look like.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909599/java-semaphore-north-south-que?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only block the *entry* to the protected area. Put the semaphores there.

Actually, you should use one semaphore, with 1 permit, because you have 1 protectable resource. The trains (`Thread`s) will acquire it before they enter, and release after they left the station.